Copying a template folder from my Wordpress to a Nextcloud server after a push on a button on my Wordpress site
I am building an Online Musician website to Collaborate in making music. Ive setup an Nextcloud server for the storage of the files and created an Wordpress website with a forum to connect to people is the idea.
Now I have made up a folder structure that I want to be created on my Nextcloud server too keep things organized.
I wrote a PowerShell script asking the collaborators what the Name of the collaboration should be. And that name is used after the folders copy to rename the copied folders to.
Now of course this works awesome for myself in local testing purposes. But now I got the challenge to create a script that does do this in the live environment. That can be triggered from a button on the wordpress website (or form). How can I copy those files from the online Nextcloud template folder to the Collaborations folder and be saved in the name users can choose from the website?
To give you an idea:
Trigger from a form on the Wordpress website. The Wordpress is running on a different server in the same local subnet as the Nextcloud is running on.
Nextcloud Source: https://nc.webtrip.nl/Templates/NewCollab/*.*
Folders:
NewCollab ( root folder to be renamed )
 .\Drums
 .\Bass
 .\Guitar
 .\Keys
 .\Vocals
 .\Other instruments
 .\CollabRelFiles
 .\Synctone\Synctone.mp3
       

Nextcloud Dest: https://nc.webtrip.nl/Collabs/$NCOLLAB_NAME/*.*
Tried the below python script to copy the files only using python but guess this option is only for local file copy. But that gave an error the source could not be found. No idea if this ever will make it work do :-) So I'm bit stuck in this really now.
import os
import shutil

# Specify the source directory containing the files
source = "https://collab.webtrip.nl/wp-content/Templates/NewCollab"

# Specify the main destination directory
dest = "https://nc.webtrip.nl/s/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/"

shutil.copytree( 'source', 'dest' )

I tried several options to connect over webdav and several other scripts don't seem to work. Hoping to find a workable solution to create a template file copy triggered from my website.
